# Finding Linear Dependence Relation

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear dependence relation between the following vectors:

x1 = (1, -1, 2)

x2 = (-3, 2, 1)

x3= (1, 2, -3)

x4= (2, 3, 1)

I've already created a matrix and reduced and I know how to tell whether it is linearly independent or not, but I don't understand how to find an actual relation. Thanks

Comment: So, you are asking to find $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ such that $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4=(0,0,0)^T$.  Can you describe the problem using matrices?  You might use $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)^T$ as one of the vectors and $(0,0,0)^T$ as another.  What might be the remaining matrix?  Do you know how to solve a problem of the form $Ax=0$?

Comment: I'm still not sure how to find an actual solution to (0, 0, 0). I know it would be solving for the matrix with columns [x1 x2 x3 x4] * x = 0 vector

Comment: One of the common methods is to row reduce the matrix formed.  Have you found the row reduced form of the matrix with columns equal to $x_1,x_2,\dots$?

Comment: Yes, I've reduced it and the first three columns are pivot columns.

Comment: The exact numbers in the matrix themselves are important, not just the locations of the pivots.  The fourth column should still have numbers in it... what are they and can you see what they imply?

Comment: The column with the free variable is (3, 1, 2). So would you set the free variable equal to 1, and then solve from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are tasked with finding a nonzero solution $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ to the equation:

$$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4=\textbf{0}$$

This is the same as finding a nonzero solution $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ to the system

$$\begin{cases}1a_1-3a_2+1a_3+2a_2=0\\-1a_1+2a_2+2a_3+3a_4=0\\2a_1+1a_2-3a_3+1a_4=0\end{cases}$$

This is the same as finding a solution $[a_1,~a_2,~a_3,~a_4]^T$ to the matrix equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&1&2\\-1&2&2&3\\2&1&-3&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

In other words, we are trying to find the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of the matrix.

Row reducing 
$$rref\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&1&2\\-1&2&2&3\\2&1&-3&1\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&3\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Remembering that row-reducing a system of equations retains the solution-set of the system and reinterpreting this as a system of equations this is the system:

$$\begin{cases} 1a_1&&&+3a_4&=0\\&1a_2&&+1a_4&=0\\&&1a_3&+2a_4&=0\end{cases}$$

This tells us that for $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ to be a solution that $a_1=-3a_4, a_2=-a_4$ and $a_3=-2a_4$

Picking any number (*other than zero*) for $a_4$, we can then write a linear combination of $x_1,\dots,x_4$ resulting in zero.

> $-3x_1-x_2-2x_3+x_4=0$

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so posting it as here)
one way to find the dependency is track your row reduction steps. For example 
if these are the steps that reduced the matrix

```
R1 = R2 - R1 , 
R3 = R3 - R1,
R3 = R3 + 2R2
Now  R3 = R3 + 2R2 replace R3 and R2 from first two steps. 
So (R3 - R1) + 2(R2 - R1) = -3R1 + 2R2 + R3 = 0 (this would be the dependency between the between the rows.
```